# Autocomplete for dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, autocomplete

Sorry for asking something that has been already asked by people (for instance here :

[jQuery autocomplete for dynamically created inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663573/jquery-autocomplete-for-dynamically-created-inputs))

but i cannot make work it despite the help i found on internet.
So, i need to use Jquery autocomplete with dynamically created inputs.
My code looks as follows:

```
$("#add_ligne2").live("click", function() { ...
         if (nb_ligne < 10) {
            var html = "";
            var next_ligne = last_ligne;
            html = '<tr rel="' + next_ligne + '">';
            html += '<td><input type="text" id="autoCompleteProjets' + next_ligne + '"/></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $("#content_tr").append(html);
            $('#autoCompleteProjets1', html).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
         }
      }
      var autocomp_opt = {
         source: "/index/autocomplete",
         minLength: 2,
         select: function(event, ui) {
            /* console.log( ui.item ?
                 "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                 "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value 
             );*/
            $('.hidden').val(ui.item.id);
         }
      }
```

Comment: I believe it should be simply `$('#autoCompleteProjets1').autocomplete(...);`

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing ??

Comment: $('#autoCompleteProjets1').autocomplete(); you mean ?

Comment: My problem is simply the autocomplete is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use fixed id "autoCompleteProjets1", I believe you want "autoCompleteProjets" + next_ligne

```
$('#autoCompleteProjets' + next_ligne, html).autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
```

You might already have it, but I'll mention it anyway - make sure you initialize last_ligne outside of the anonymous function, else you create local variable, which is unset once out of scope:

```
var last_ligne = 0;
```

Then, you don't increment the last_ligne variable, use this:

```
var next_ligne = ++last_ligne;
```

And most important: use firebug in firefox, or equivalent for other browsers, to find out what you really generate.

Comment: I used this right after "$("#content_tr").append(html);" but it's not working unfortunately

Comment: Now I see you don't increment next_ligne, nor assign it to last_ligne, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The incrementation was already implemented but not visible in the block of code i posted. it's still not working unfortunately ....

Comment: then you have to post the whole code. Do you use some debugging techniques?