# jQuery event not working on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: jquery

I am loading an element through `jQuery AJAX` whose id is `questionBeanPV.coAppQuestions150.answerText` 
I know the id is too long and it contains jQuery's `'.'` but i cannot change the id.

I want a funnction to be called when this element is clicked. However the following code is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#questionBeanPV\\.coAppQuestions150\\.answerText').click(function(){
        alert('Hello !');
    });
});
```

I have observed that this doesnt work for any dynamically loaded element. What am i missing ?
Is this the correct way or some other way is there?

Comment: The event listener should be attached to the document, so any new elements that created after attaching the listener can be considered to fire the event.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

```
$('body').on('click', '#questionBeanPV\\.coAppQuestions150\\.answerText', function() {
    alert('Hello !');
});
```

This technique will helps you to attach any event to dynamically created elements.

Comment: Maybe you'd post another question with relevant code. We'll try to help you :-)

Comment: here ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303650/jquery-autocomplete-not-working-on-dynamically-loaded-elements?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663573/jquery-autocomplete-for-dynamically-created-inputs

Answer (score 1):

you should use [***delegate***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click","#questionBeanPV\\.coAppQuestions150\\.answerText",function(){
   //some operation
});
```

It helps you to attach handlers for the future elements

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", "#questionBeanPV\\.coAppQuestions150\\.answerText", function() {
```