# jQuery autocomplete not working on dynamically loaded elements

Tags: jquery

I am loading an element through jQuery AJAX whose id is `172`.
Now i want to apply autocomplete on this element.
However the following code is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   $( "#172" ).autocomplete({
                minLength: 2,      
                source: function(request, response) {
                    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(jsonCities, request.term);
                    response(results.slice(0, 10));
                },      
                focus: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                    $( "#172" ).val( ui.item.label );        
                    return false;      
                },      
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#172" ).val( ui.item.label );        
                    $( "#172-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                    return false;      
                }    
            });
});
```

I have observed that this doesnt work for any dynamically loaded element. What am i missing ? Is this the correct way or some other way is there?

Comment: Just use the $("").autocomplete() on the success: function of the $.ajax({}) for that element, since your object is not on the DOM on the document ready the selector returns an empty array.

Comment: It was there when I opened the question, so who knows =S

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
$.ajax({
url:"..."
type:"...",
success:function(){
    //Add your #172 element and then use autocomplete on it
    $( "#172" ).autocomplete({}) 
}

});
```

Since your element is not on the DOM when you call the autocomplete function nothing gets the autocomplete behavior, use if after you add the element to the DOM in your Ajax call.