# Autocomplete input field not working in bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I am working on a web development project and I am using bootstrap tabs there. I am dynamically creating them using add and remove input field section, according to that number of inputs I am creating the tabs in the same page using ajax.

In that tabs I have the same form with same input fields. There is a input field with autocomplete function in that form. I am taking data from mysql to that field. My problem is **autocomplete is only working in the first tab** not in the others. Autocomplete field label is **Responsible**

This is my function.

```
function autocompletT() {
  var min_length = 0;
  var keyword = $('#responsible_id').val();
  if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax_refresh2.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {keyword:keyword},
      success:function(data){

        $('#responsible_id_list').show();
        $('#responsible_id_list').html(data);

        $('#responsible_id_list li').click(function() {

          var txx = $(this).text();
          var tcust = $(this).val();

         });

      }
    });
  } else {
    $('#responsible_id_list').hide();
  }

}

  // set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
  // change input value
  $('#responsible_id').val(item);
  // hide proposition list
  $('#responsible_id_list').hide();
}
```

Portion of My code

```
<div class="col-md-6 entire_div">
            <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <?php
                             for ($row = 0; $row < $agenda_size; $row++) {
                                 $p_agenda = $mAgenda[$row];   
                                 $row_plus = $row + 1;
                        ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo '#'.$row_plus?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $p_agenda; ?></a></li>
                        <?php

                                }   
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <?php
                             for ($row = 0; $row < $agenda_size; $row++) {
                                 $p_agenda = $mAgenda[$row]; 
                                 $row_plus = $row + 1;    
                        ?>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="<?php echo $row_plus;?>">




  <!-- form -->
  <form class="ws-validate">  

  <div class="form-group"> 
    <label for="responsible_id" class="control-label">Responsible</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsible_id" name="zip" placeholder="Select Responsible Person" onkeyup="autocompletT()" >
    <ul id="responsible_id_list"></ul>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group"> 
    <button id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
<!--     <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Add"> -->

  </div>     

</form>  


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="table-responsive">

            <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">

              <thead>

                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                 <th>Action</th>
                 <th>Start Date</th>
                 <th>Due Date</th>
                 <th>Status</th>
                 <th>Responsible</th>

              </thead>
    <tbody>


    </tbody>

</table>
   <div class="delete_b_class">

        <button id="delete_row" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Row</button>

   </div>

            </div>

        </div>
  </div>

<div class="submit_all_div">

  <input class="submit_all_b" id="submit" onclick="myDataSendFunction()" type="button" value="Submit">

</div> 

                                </div>
                        <?php

                                }   
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**ids are unique**

- Each element can have only one id
- Each page can have only one element with that id

**classes are NOT unique**

- You can use the same class on multiple elements.
- You can use multiple classes on the same element.

Probably, you are creating so many **#responsible_id** and **#responsible_id_list** with your **php** code.

So, as  IDs must be unique. use the a unique ID for each search field (which is responsible_id  ) and list (which is responsible_id_list ) here.

You can get a idea from here:-  *remove **onkeyup="autocompletT"** function from the input and add  jquery event like this. then find the next **responsible_id_list** then  populate list  and  append list to it.*

```
$('.responsible_id').keyup(function(){
     var min_length = 0;
     var keyword = $(this).val() ;
     ///others codes

     //say
     var list='';
     $(this).next('.responsible_id_list').html(list);

})
```

Comment: i put class instead of id, then after i selected a name from any tab that name apply to all fields in every tab. how should i created different ids according to the number of tabs.?

Comment: @D.Madu please check the updates. let me know if  anything required

Answer (score -1):

You might need to re-initialize the autocomplete on the inputs every time. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663573/jquery-autocomplete-for-dynamically-created-inputs) question to get a braoder picture. This should solve your concerns